# Typing Unicode Symbols in VS Code

Tags: macos, unicode, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble typing the Ω symbol (U+03A9) in the Visual Studio Code editor.

On my Mac, I can usually type this with <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> but it doesn't seem to work in Code.

Many other combinations seem to work just fine (for example, ≈ <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> inputs correctly).

I'm wondering if VS Code is intercepting <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> for some other keyboard shortcut.  I searched for a list of keyboard shortcuts but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: does it work in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

⌥Z is bound to toggle word wrap.

> You can toggle word wrap for the VS Code session with ⌥Z. Restarting VS Code will pick up the persisted editor.wrappingColumn value.
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_common-questions

In the `Default Keyboard Shortcuts` it shows up as:

```
{ 
  "key": "alt+z",
  "command": "editor.action.toggleWordWrap",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

> To remove a specific key binding, simply add a `-` to the `command` and the rule will be a removal rule.
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule

Your `keybindings.json` file should include the following:

```
{
  "key": "alt+z",
  "command": "-editor.action.toggleWordWrap",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

I have confirmed that this is working on VSCode for Mac.

Comment: As a side note - make sure to restart code after making the change.  If you don't restart, the keybinding ends up toggling word wrap and simultaneously inserting a Ω character.